# Where are KDE themes located?

Tags: themes, kde

I want to modify a few icons in the theme.

How would I go about modifying them, and moreover where are they located?

Comment: Try these:`~/themes`, `~/.themes`, `~/.kde/share/themes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Systemwide themes are placed in `/usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/` but you can copy to  `~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/` if you want to customize for a user.

KDE Icons are place in `/usr/share/icons` or in `~/.kde/share/icons`.
(**KDE5**: `/usr/share/icons` or ~/.local/share/icons`)

On the following link there's an nice example on how to customize a theme: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56120-Customize-plasma-desktop-theme .